# Unable to configure Swagger in Spring project, getting File not found exception

Tags: java, spring, rest, swagger, springfox

I am trying to configure swagger for my spring application. Below is the configuration. However, getting an error

[springfox/documentation/spring/web/SpringfoxWebMvcConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Spring version - 4.0.4
Springfox version - 2.9.2

It's NOT a maven project, I have all the required jar files added to the classpath.

Spring-context.xml

```
<bean id="Swagger" class="skt.test.SwaggerConfig" />

<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

Swagger config class

```
package skt.test;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();

    }

}
```

**Jar files included**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPp3E.png

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: skt.test.SwaggerConfig; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [springfox/documentation/spring/web/SpringfoxWebMvcConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:160)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:299)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [springfox/documentation/spring/web/SpringfoxWebMvcConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:82)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:77)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:551)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getRelated(ConfigurationClassParser.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getAnnotationAttributes(ConfigurationClassParser.java:741)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.collectImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:366)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:340)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:206)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:426)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:206)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:174)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:156)
    ... 39 more
```

Comment: I feel that there is something wrong with your project config, since your'e not getting any compile time error while .class files are missing, so it would be great if you share your project in github for taking a look at it.

Comment: I wish i could do it. But I am afraid that I won't be able to share the project files publicly. It's a corporate project

Comment: Another good option is creating a helloworld project with the same config to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Note: I also faced same issue and found that it is due to some maven build problem, Please remove all the swagger code and imports form the project and try to run your project.

Answer (score 8):

You need below library ,

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you are not using pom just download it from

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/2.5.0
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.5.0

To get more insight you can follow here 
https://github.com/mayurbavisiya/Spring4Swagger

In your spring file you need to write

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html"/>
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: I have added both of the above jars in my class path (v2.9.2)
https://i.imgur.com/8YPVJfE.png
And May I know how different is the resource mapping provided by you with the one I have included in the post?

Comment: classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html

Comment: The classes have been deprecated, that's why reverting to an older version fixed the problem. I think the best solution is to migrate to Open API 3.

Comment: not the versions of bot dependencies should be the same

Comment: Updating to 3.0.0 as @Mak suggested is what resolved it for me.   Tnx

Comment: Note: I also faced same issue and found that it is due to some maven build problem, Please remove all the swagger code and imports form the project and try to run your project.